# npm installでエラー

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

Macの新しい環境で npm install したところ下記のエラーが出てました。
package.jsonがあるディレクトリで npm install しました。
どのあたりを調べたらいいかご教授おねがいします。

```
環境
MacOS ELCAPITAN 10.11.4
% node -v                                                                                                                    
v0.11.11

% gulp -v                                                                                                                     (git)-[master]
[02:12:17] CLI version 3.9.1
[02:12:17] Local version 3.9.1

> node-sass@3.4.2 install /Users/xxx/phpstorm/bbs/resources/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Binary downloaded and installed at /Users/xxx/phpstorm/bbs/resources/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-14/binding.node

> node-sass@3.4.2 postinstall /Users/xxx/phpstorm/bbs/resources/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

` /Users/xxx/phpstorm/bbs/resources/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-14/binding.node ` exists. 
 testing binary.
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN2v814ObjectTemplate3NewEPNS_7IsolateE
  Referenced from: /Users/xxx/phpstorm/bbs/resources/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-14/binding.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN2v814ObjectTemplate3NewEPNS_7IsolateE
  Referenced from: /Users/xxx/phpstorm/bbs/resources/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-14/binding.node
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Answer (score 2):

一度 `node_modules/` を削除して、`npm install` し直してみるとどうでしょうか。

違う環境でインストールした際の残骸が残っていると、そのようなエラーが起きるような気がします。

参考 [dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30130692/2818869)

Comment: /usr/local/lib/node_modulesを削除してnode.jsを再度インストールしましたら正常に動きました！